# Updating href attributes in link tags

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I would like to change the href attributes of the link tags that have the following attribute :

```
rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed"
```

Does anyone know how to achieve that ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ext.select](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext-method-select) can be used to search for DOM elements.  To understand how to select elements in the DOM, one may have a look at jQuery [Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) documentation.

[Ext.dom.Element.set](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element-method-set) can then  be used to change the href attribute.  Note that even if [Ext.select](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext-method-select) returns a collection, all methods of Ext.Element can be used on the collection.

In short, this gives something like this:

```
Ext.select("a[rel='apple-touch-icon-precomposed']").set({href: 'my-other-link.html'});
```